# Gradle with C++: How to change compiler options?

Tags: c++, gradle, build.gradle

I'm starting to work with Gradle and have just built a couple things. The build generated the file "options.txt":

```
-x
c++
-c
-I
/path/to/project/src/main/headers
-I
/path/to/project/src/hello/headers
-m64
```

That's cool that they choose compiler options for me but for example I'd like to compile my stuff with -std=c++17 and -Wall and -Wextra. So how can I add these flags to the g++ options?

Comment: Just add them on separate lines. Apparently every line corresponds to one command line argument.

Comment: No this file is generated by a call to gradle. If I edit this, gradle will overwrite it with the next call to "gradle clean build".

Answer (score 6):

Just add the following inside 'model' in build.gradle:

```
toolChains {
    gcc(Gcc) {
        eachPlatform {
            cppCompiler.withArguments { args ->
                args << "-std=c++17"
            }
            cppCompiler.withArguments { args ->
                args << "-Wall"
            }
            cppCompiler.withArguments { args ->
                args << "-Wextra"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that groovy or kotlin script?